# table with json data from angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two json file I want to generate a dynamic table using anything like angularjs/jquery. I tried angularjs ng-repeat but not succeed.

first JSON

```
$scope.myHospital = [
  {"name":"hos1"}, 
  {"name":"hos2"},
  {"name":"hos3"},
  {"name":"hos4"},
  {"name":"hos5"}
];
```

Second JSON

```
$scope.data = [{
  "category":"first category",
  "procedure":[{
      "name":"pro1",
      "hospital": [
        {"price":"344"},
        {"price":"467"},
        {"price":"423"},
        {"price":"674"},
        {"price":"313"}
      ]
  }, {
    "name":"pro2",
    "hospital": [
      {"price":"234"},
      {"price":"568"},
      {"price":"136"},
      {"price":"567"},
      {"price":"666"}
    ]
  }, {
    "name":"pro3",
    "hospital": [
      {"price":"349"},
      {"price":"469"},
      {"price":"429"},
      {"price":"679"},
      {"price":"319"}
    ]
  }]
}];
```

And I want a table like this. Is it possible then please provide me a solution or if not then what changes required in my JSON to achieve this.Thanks 
[image: expected output table]

Comment: `$scope.myHospital` and `$scope.data` dosent have common key to map.So how would you decide which price should go for which hospital?

Comment: currently, I am trying to achieve this for ideal situation like each time I have 5 hospitals and they are in sequence.If it is not sounds good than I can merge both JSON like in first JSON I can add hospital name with price.

Comment: like this "procedure":[
                {
                             "name":"pro1",
                              "hospital":                      
                                [
                                    {"name":"hos1","price":"344"},
                                    {"name":"hos2","price":"467"},
                                    {"name":"hos3","price":"423"},
                                    {"name":"hos4","price":"674"},
                                    {"name":"hos5","price":"313"}
                                ]
                },

Comment: yea that will do I guess ! can you post that changed JSON data in question I will come up with answer

Comment: @Harshsachdev why do you have `$scope.data` as an array. Is it okay to treat it as object for now? Check my answer with that assumption.

Comment: Thanks @Angular_10

Comment: @Angular_10 please have a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189639/angularjs-table-using-json-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have nested `ng-repeat` in order to achieve this. Assuming first hospital price maps to `hos1`, you can do something like this,

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(hosIndex, hos) in myHospital">
    <td width="100px" ng-bind="hos.name"></td>
    <td width="100px" ng-repeat="pro in data[0].procedure" 
    ng-bind="pro.hospital[hosIndex].price">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nYKbkm5KT5bDSHCvtYC?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @tanmay. Can you please have a look at this                              [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/mETIq6Ry2xIcy1LccInG?p=preview) in this case added a field "id" because in some cases. I don't get prices for every hospital. Hope you will understand the problem please have a look at "pro3" posted link.

Comment: For "pro3" i want null value for hospital 1 & 4 because they don't have any price.

Comment: @Harshsachdev can you make that `null` programmatically in the JSON itself (by running `angular.forEach` or similar way), cause it would be kinda tough to achieve that just using `ng-repeat`. **OR** if the JSON is controlled by you, can you keep `{"id": "1", "price": null}` in the JSON itself?

Comment: actually, the JSON is not controlled by me I am getting it from backend. but I can alter it after receiving it.So how I add "price":null for the blank hospitals after receiving it.

Comment: Or somehow can I achieve this by matching the id's of hospitals ?

Comment: please have a look at this, this is exactly what i want  [NEW QUESTION] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189639/angularjs-table-using-json-data)

Comment: @Harshsachdev I have added an answer to your new question. good luck!